# Appscript addon triggers are set inside my addon project, instead of user's spreadsheet's appscript project

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I am creating an appscript addon named `Everyday Addon` which create trigger named `Trigger1` which runs every day.

`Trigger1` can be set by `Add Trigger` button in addon homepage. Similarly it can be removed by `Remove Trigger` button. Similarly remove button is also working, but working on my Addon Appscript project.

Testing:

1. Project deployed as test add on.
2. Addon installed.
3. I create a new spreadsheet named `Test SS`. It has my addon already installed.
4. I click `Add Trigger` button.

Results:
`Trigger1` is created but it is created on my `Everyday Addon` Appscript project. It is not created on the new spreadsheet- `Test SS`.

What did I got wrong? Should not the trigger sit on `Test SS` spreadsheet's project?
If 100's of user install my addon then 100 of Trigger will sit on my Addon project?

Comment: Can you provide your code that creates the trigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is intended behaviour!

The trigger that you create programmatically will be attached to the add-on rather than the target Spreadsheet - this is because the function you intend to run on trigger is in the add-on project file, not the target Sheet's bound script.

That being said - this is per-user behaviour. You won't have hundreds of triggers all bound to your script project after publishing because each time a trigger is created by a user it will be tied to their account and not yours.

**Remember:** the Apps Script Quotas limit triggers to [20 per user per script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations), so each user can have up to 20 triggers installed via your add-on before they will not be able to install any more.

**Further reading:** as per the documentation on [testing editor add-ons](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/how-tos/testing-editor-addons#testing_details):

> [Installable triggers](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/concepts/editor-triggers#installable_triggers_in_add-ons) aren't supported when testing. Functionality that depends on installable triggers are not testable.